How to detect system dialog is being shown on top of activity?
I'm working on an app that shows video content and we support PiP (picture-in-picture) mode, when user presses Home button. We trigger the pip mode in onUserLeaveHint() method, as the docs suggest.
 protected void onUserLeaveHint() {
     super.onUserLeaveHint();
     enterPipMode();
}

The problem we have at the moment is that any system dialog (like dialog for permissions when connecting phone to computer, allow Usb debugging) that appears on top of our video content activity is calling the onUserLeaveHint(). I know that this method is called when you switch to another activity and system dialogs are different activities on most cases.
So the question is: How can we detect that a system dialog is being shown at the moment?
I've look around but didn't find any solution that works for me.
So far I tried different approaches to get a flag that can be used in order to prevent enterPipMode() being called in cases there is there is a dialog, but for the moment I didn't find a robust solution that covers all the system dialogs and use cases.
Thing that I tried:

using the ActivityManager

       .getSystemService(Activity.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    String className = activityManager.getRunningTasks(1).get(0).topActivity.getClassName();


detecting the focus of the activity

override fun onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus: Boolean) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus)
        if (!hasFocus) {
            //todo your logic
        }
    }


BroadCastReceiver to listen for events of the phone being plugged

    private BroadcastReceiver mPowerConnectionReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
                if (action.equals(Intent.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED)) {
                    booleanFlag = true;
                } else if (action.equals(Intent.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED)) {
                    booleanFlag = false;
                }
            }
        }
    };


or something like this
    public boolean isConnected() {
        Intent intent = this.registerReceiver(
                null,
                new IntentFilter("android.hardware.usb.action.USB_STATE")
        );
        if (intent != null && intent.getExtras() != null) {
            return intent.getExtras().getBoolean("adb") ||
                    intent.getExtras().getBoolean("connected");
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }


Also tried to get it via reflection.
Only the approach with the BroadCastReceiver gave some results but there is no good way to know when to clear the flag and there is no PiP mode while the device is connected and we don't cover all the possible system dialogs.
I can see that Google Maps has PiP and it's working fine there :)
Let me know if any additional information is needed.
Thanks!

So after a few days of trying different approaches, I've managed to get the behaviour I need - to see Pip only when user taps on the Home button. It's a bit different from the original approach in the question, but hopefully it can help someone.
I've added a receiver to listen for home button events, as described here and a function to check if user is still in the same activity.
    private final BroadcastReceiver homeButtonClickReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    final String SYSTEM_DIALOG_REASON_KEY = "reason";
    final String SYSTEM_DIALOG_REASON_HOME_KEY = "homekey";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS.equals(action)) {
            String reason = intent.getStringExtra(SYSTEM_DIALOG_REASON_KEY);
            if (reason != null) {
                if (reason.equals(SYSTEM_DIALOG_REASON_HOME_KEY)) {
                    shouldEnterPip = isInVideoScreenActivity();
                }
            }
        }
    }
};

private boolean isInVideoScreenActivity() {
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService(Activity.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    final List<ActivityManager.AppTask> appTasks = manager.getAppTasks();
    final ComponentName componentName = appTasks.get(0).getTaskInfo().topActivity;
    final String className;
    if (componentName != null) {
        className = componentName.getClassName();
        Toast.makeText(this, "onReceive(): " + className, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return className.equals(VideoScreenActivity.class.getName());
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

I use shouldEnterPip flag to determine if PiP should be opened and every time we enter PiP mode, we clear the flag to avoid some unwanted behaviour.
 @Override
 protected void onUserLeaveHint() {
    super.onUserLeaveHint();
    if (shouldEnterPip) {
        enterPipMode();
        shouldEnterPip = false;
   }
 }

That's it. Let me know what are the flaws of this solution and if there is a better way to solve this problem.
